# The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 36 bytes

Tags: c#, rsa

I'm trying to make a password safe, but theres something wrong with how I use RSA.
Heres my codes:

```
    private void testencodedecode()
    {
        string mehdi = "mehdi";
        var enc = encodePass(mehdi);
        var dec = decodePass(enc);
    }
    private RSAParameters rsaKey()
    {
        var setting = context.Settings.First(s => s.ID == 1);

        byte[] pwd = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(setting.PWDKEY);

        byte[] expo = {1,0,1};

        var key = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters();
        key.Exponent = expo;
        key.Modulus = pwd;

        return key;
    }

    private string encodePass(string pass)
    {
        var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        provider.ImportParameters(rsaKey());

        var encryptedBytes = provider.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass), false);

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encryptedBytes);
    }

    private string decodePass(string pass)
    {
       var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
       provider.ImportParameters(rsaKey());
       string decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(provider.Decrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass), true));
       return decrypted;
    }
```

It seems to encrypt fine, but on decryption has the following error:

> The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 36 bytes.

Comment: Unless you have an absolute requirement to retrieve the password in plain text (most applications *don't* need this) you should be hashing (with salt), not encrypting.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever as I mentioned its a password safe, so the user needs to see the passwords he saves, i thought about the sha1 and md5 but theres no way to retrieve them, so yeah its necessery to have it encrypted.

Comment: Ah. I read "safe" as an adjective, not a noun. As in, I thought you were trying to make it safe *from* attack.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever its ok :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some major issues with the method here. The first, as you mentioned in a comment on another answer is that you're using a `Guid` to construct the RSA modulus, which is entirely invalid. You cannot use random data to construct the public key directly for a number of reasons:

1. The modulus must conform to a specific structure, i.e. it is the product of two *large* prime numbers, whereas your `Guid` in binary form generally will not be.
2. In order to decrypt the RSA-encrypted data, you must know the two primes used to generate the modulus. Even if your random modulus was magically the product of two large primes you wouldn't be able to determine them, since this would require factoring the modulus, which is an intentionally difficult thing to do (indeed, the difficulty is the entire basis of RSA's security).

You should be generating the RSA key using the `RsaCryptoServiceProvider` constructor e.g.:

```
// Construct the RsaCryptoServiceProvider, and create a new 2048bit key
var csp = new RsaCryptoServiceProvider(2048);
```

The parameters for this newly generated key can then be exported:

```
// Export the RSA parameters, including the private parameters
var parameters = csp.ExportParameters(true);
```

The parameters can then be stored (**securely**) and used to re-initialize the CSP for decryption later.

There are also other obvious problems, such as the fact that the amount of data you can actually encrypt with RSA is limited by the key size, so with a 2048 bit key as created above, you can encrypt 2048 / 8 - 11 = 245 bytes (where the 11 bytes is a result of the PKCS#1 v1.5 padding that is applied). If you want to encrypt more than this, the general method is to use a symmetric cipher (e.g. AES) to encrypt the data, and then use RSA only to encrypt the AES key.

Finally, whilst this may work, I still wouldn't rely on it for security as there are almost always issues with roll-your-own encryption schemes.

Answer (score 0):

The modulus for RSA should be at least 1024 bits (128 bytes). Anything less will be completely insecure. And for modern applications it is even recommended to use a 2048 or larger modulus.

And secondly, you are not generating the RSA keys properly! You shouldn't just use the password as a modulus..

The public exponent and the modulus must be chosen such that the exponent is relatively prime to `p-1` for all primes `p` which divide the modulus. If you are just arbitrarily setting the modulus to a binary representation of a password (`PWDKEY`) it's unlikely that you are choosing an appropriate exponent/modulus pair. And as I said earlier the modulus must be a relatively large number, usually chosen to be 1024, 2048 or 4096 bits long.

Comment: im using a guide for its pwd, isn't it enough?

Comment: Guid g = Guid.NewGuid();
setting.PWDKEY = g.ToString();

Comment: so i need to divide the modulus and find the appropriate exponent? im new to rsa encoding, I just want to do it in a simple way.

Comment: generating the RSA key manually is not recommended. .NET provides a standard way to generate a key-pair (you will need both public and private keys in order to do anything useful) and you should use that, or import a key-pair that was previously generated. Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e9ft273(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: The reason using a GUID is not a good idea in the first place is that while GUIDs are unique and appear random, they are not cryptographically secure. And second is that a GUID is a 128 bit number while an RSA modulus should be at least 1024 bits.

Comment: i have to use a manual key. so how can i get my key to be right to my modulus. im generating a unique GUID for every user and i use that for the encryption.

Comment: Then you'd better read up on how to properly generate one. But I'm hard pressed to see why you **need** to use a manual key..

Comment: the key i create manually is not only a key, it contains some crucial data about the user and some private stuffs in that guide. and thanks for the help. it was really useful.

Comment: remember one very important thing though: the keys must be **randomly** indistinguishable from random in order to be crypto-secure. it's ok to **derive** a key from some non-random information but not ok to use that directly. And the derivation process must use a crypto-secure pseudo random number generator. Be very careful when you generate the key. It would be wise perhaps to ask another question in which to detail your crpyto scheme to be reviewed by other experts!

Comment: i just read this article on RSA: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt.aspx which is hardcoded the rsa modulus and exponent. also another in codeproject had done this, so i dont really get how to make a proper KEY. isn't the exponent something fixed? coz in every article i've read it was {1,0,1}

Comment: @MehdiGhanavatian The exponent is generally one of a common set of values, e.g. 65537 (which is the decimal value of {1, 0, 1} which you're using).