# RSA decryption?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I follow this example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10877/Public-Key-RSA-Encryption-in-C-NET

Encrypt a file is Ok.. but When I decrypt, they throw an exception:
The data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 256 bytes.
I try to debug and recognize that may by this line is wrong:

```
int base64BlockSize = ((dwSize / 8) % 3 != 0) ? (((dwSize / 8) / 3) * 4) + 4 : ((dwSize / 8) / 3) * 4;
```

The encryptedBytes.Length is 258... bigger than 256??? How can I fix this???

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389421/the-data-to-be-decrypted-exceeds-the-maximum-for-this-modulus-of-36-bytes

Comment: Don't split the file into blocks, use hybrid encryption instead.

Comment: oh thank you... :D.. I have already fixed it. :D